# update array to mockAPI

Tags: javascript, api, async-await

I have such an object on `mockAPI`

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "name": "qqq",
   "email": "qqq",
   "password": "qqq",
   "tasks": [],
   "gettingTasks": [],
}
```

And I want to add to the array `"tasks"` several  `"ids"`

```
const createTaskUser = (id, idTask) => {
const user = usersGateway.fetchUser(id)   here i query the user and get the object as above
const newUser = {
    ...user,
     tasks:idTask
    }
usersGateway.updateUser(id, newUser) is a function that accepts a user id that needs to be updated and a new dataset
}
```

If I run this function it will overwrite the values, but I need to have the data added. 
After a few calls the array should looks like this:

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "name": "qqq",
   "email": "qqq",
   "password": "qqq",
   "tasks": [1,4,75,3,2],
   "gettingTasks": [],
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you using something like https://www.mockapi.io or are you working with this object in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can push in array or use spread operator. check step `tasks: [...user.tasks, idTask]`**

```
const createTaskUser = (id, idTask) => {
  const user = usersGateway.fetchUser(id); // here i query the user and get the object as above
  const newUser = {
    ...user,
    tasks: [...user.tasks, idTask]
  };
  usersGateway.updateUser(id, newUser); //is a function that accepts a user id that needs to be updated and a new dataset
};
```

**// If push allowed**

```
const createTaskUser = (id, idTask) => {
  const user = usersGateway.fetchUser(id); // here i query the user and get the object as above
  user.tasks.push(idTask)
  usersGateway.updateUser(id, user); //is a function that accepts a user id that needs to be updated and a new dataset
};
```